# Type mismatch found Unit, required Future[Customer] on flatmap

Tags: scala, functional-programming, future, flatmap

I have the below code and in my `findOrCreate()` function, I'm getting an error saying `Type mismatch found Unit, required Future[Customer]`. The `customerByPhone()` function that is being called inside `findOrCreate()` also contains calls that are expecting Futures, which is why I'm using a fatmap. I don't know why the result of the flatmap is resulting in `Unit`. What am I doing wrong?

```
override def findOrCreate(phoneNumber: String, creationReason: String): Future[AvroCustomer] =  {

  //query for customer in db
  val avroCustomer: Future[AvroCustomer] = customerByPhone(phoneNumber).flatMap(_ => createUserAndEvent(phoneNumber, creationReason, 1.0))

}

override def customerByPhone(phoneNumber: String): Future[AvroCustomer] = {
  val query = Schema.Customers.byPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
  val dbAction: DBIO[Option[Schema.Customer]] = query.result.headOption

  db.run(dbAction)
    .map(_.map(AvroConverters.toAvroCustomer).orNull)
}

private def createUserAndEvent(phoneNumber: String, creationReason: String, version: Double): Future[AvroCustomer] = {

  val query = Schema.Customers.byPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
  val dbAction: DBIO[Option[Schema.Customer]] = query.result.headOption

  val data: JsValue = Json.obj(
    "phone_number" -> phoneNumber,
    "agent_number" -> "placeholder for agent number",
    "creation_reason" -> creationReason
  )
  //empty for now
  val metadata: JsValue = Json.obj()

  //creates user
  val avroCustomer: Future[AvroCustomer] = db.run(dbAction).map(_.map(AvroConverters.toAvroCustomer).orNull)
  avroCustomer.onComplete({
    case Success(null) => {

    }

    //creates event
    case Success(customer) => {
      val uuid: UUID = UUID.fromString(customer.id)
      //create event
      val event: Future[CustomerEvent] = db.run(Schema.CustomerEvents.create(
        uuid,
        "customer_creation",
        version,
        data,
        metadata)
      ).map(AvroConverters.toAvroEvent)
    }
    case Failure(exception) => {

    }
  })

  Future.successful(new AvroCustomer)
}
```

Comment: A `val` statement returns `Unit`.

Comment: @Reactormonk to my knowledge, a val just makes the variable immutable, but you can return any value?

Comment: `val foo: Int = { val bar = 32 }` will give you a compile error.

Comment: `val` creates the immutable variable with the specified value but it doesn't return that value like it does in a language like C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Reactormonk basically answered this in the comments, I'm going to actually write an answer with some details. His comment that a `val` statement produces `Unit` is fundamentally correct, but I'm hoping some elaboration will make things more clear.

The key element that I see is that `val` is a declaration. Declarations in Scala are statements that don't produce useful values. Because of the functional nature of Scala, they do produce a value, but it is `Unit` and as there is only one instance of `Unit`, it doesn't carry any meaning.

The reason programmers new to Scala are often tempted to do something like this is that they don't think of blocks of code as statements and are often used to using `return` in other languages. So let's consider a simplified function here.

```
def foo(i: Int): Int = {
  42 * i
}
```

I include a code block as I think that is key to this error, though it really isn't needed here. The value of a code block is simply the value of the last expression in the code block. This is why we don't have to specify `return`, but most programmers who are used to `return` are a bit uncomfortable with that naked expression at the end of a block. That is why it is tempting to throw in the `val` declaration.

```
def foo(i: Int): Int = {
  val result = 42 * i // Error: type mismatch.
}
```

Of course, as was mentioned, but `val` results in `Unit` making this incorrect. You could add an extra line with just `result`, and that will compile, but it is overly verbose and non-idiomatic.

Scala supports the use of `return` to leave a method/function and give back a particular value, though the us is generally frowned upon. As such, the following code works.

```
def foo(i: Int): Int = {
  return 42 * i
}
```

While you shouldn't use `return` in Scala code, I feel that imagining it being there can help with understanding what is wrong here. If you stick a `return` in front of the `val` you get code like the following.

```
def foo(i: Int): Int = {
  return val result = 42 * i // Error: type mismatch.
}
```

At least to me, this code is clearly incorrect. The `val` is a declaration and as such it just doesn't work with a `return`. It takes some time to get used to the functional style of blocks as expressions. Until you get to that point, it might help just to act like there is a `return` at the end of methods without actually putting one there.

It is worth noting that, in the comments, jwvh claims that a declaration like this in C would return a value. That is false. **Assignments** in most C-family languages give back the value that was assigned, so `a = 5` returns the value `5`, but declarations don't, so `int a = 5;` does not give back anything and can't be used as an expression.